# Unity C# Deserialization dealing with extra properties

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to save data about my game made in Unity, written in C#. I am able to serialize my data and deserialize it. The problem comes when I have deserialize a file and the class I serialized has had a property removed. When this happens a `SerializationException` is thrown.
**Example**:
Lets say I have this initial class:

```
[Serializable]
public class foo {
    public int bar;
    public int baz;
}
```

Then I serialize it to a file. I then modify this class and remove `public int baz`. Next time I try and deserialize that file it will throw an exception because it can't find a spot to put `baz` in class `foo`.

Is there a way I can tell the deserializer to ignore extra properties or to cast class `foo` as something that can handle extra objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Json.NET? It is tolerant of extra properties (along with being much faster and having other added features).

I just tested with (saving with bar and baz, then removing baz, and deserializing):

```
public class foo {
    public int bar {get;set;}
    public int baz {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Sure! Here you go: https://gist.github.com/ThreeScreenStudios/a397e795f1e561b3118f

(run the serialization code first to save an object to a file, then comment that out, and run the file read/deserialization code)

Comment: Do you know if this will work on all platforms in Unity?

Comment: Not sure, sorry - looks like this person made a port might work with all platforms, but you have to pay: http://www.parentelement.com/assets/json_net_unity

Answer (score 1):

I believe you looking for Version Tolerant Serialization...  Read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Do you know if you can do something like this? `[OptionalField]... whole bunch of feilds...[/OptionalField]

Comment: @NoahHuppert No.  Attributes need to be applied on a field-by-field basis.